# How i create common save/update/delete operations in one base class in php?

Tags: php

How i create common save/update/delete operations in one base class or model in  core php with example.there are 27 table  in my database.thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `Model` and `core php` ?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at google first. There are many examples for such typical CRUD implementations out on the internet... Problem with this question is that it cannot really be answered without a _huge_ effort. Since basically what you ask here is: explain to me everything I need to know for programming php, working with a database, knowing about patterns, ... This site is to ask _specific_ questions about implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Class

```
class DBController {
 private $host;
 .....
 private $conn
 function __constuct(){
  $this->$conn = new mysqli($host,....);
}
 // save operation 
 function insertQuery($sql){
  $check=$this->conn->query($sql);
  other check 

 }
 function updateQuery($sql){
  $check=$this->conn->query($sql);
  other checks.. 

 }
}
```

**Now include this class in required files and make instance of it and call "select query" function on insertion and so forth**

Comment: can you describe with details with example ..it will benefit for me.thanks in advace.

Comment: first try something and post some code so it would be easy to figure out where you have stuck

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)         private $sql; 
 private $conn;
 function __constuct(){
  $this->$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname)  or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  /*
  $this->$sql = "INSERT INTO `talentagency`.`agents` (`id`, `email`, `full_name`, `password`, `joining_date`,
 `email_token`, `is_active`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `phone`, `country`, `zip_code`, `comment`) VALUES (NULL, 'santu@gmail.com', 'ssss', 'ssssss', '2015-07-10 00:00:00', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'dsasss');";
 */
}